# ArgumentException when initialising WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write a simple program in WPF where the entire window is taken up by an image whose source is a WriteableBitmap that I draw. Here is the relevant code:

```
var image = m_Window.CustomImage;
image.Source = new WriteableBitmap(
    (int) image.ActualWidth,
    (int) image.ActualHeight,
    300,
    300,
    PixelFormats.Bgra32,
    null
);
```

but when I run this I get `System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range` on the constructor. Frustratingly it does not say which value is incorrect. I have tried googling but there have been precious few examples of a WriteableBitmap constructor, and those that do exist are what generated the above code in the first place. Any advice?

Comment: try using `300d`, it's expecting a `double`, or `300.00`.

Comment: try other value for dpi, for example `96` instead `300`

Comment: Explicitly casting to double or using double primitives has no effect and in any case Resharper assures me it's not necessary. I have tried `72`, `96` and `300` but none of these work.

Comment: In fact no number between 0 and 1000 works so I'm going to assume the problem is with another of the parameters.

Comment: What are `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`?

Comment: Ohh they were both 0 which explains the ArgumentException. Edit: I would mark this question as answered but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Comment: To mark the question as answered, there has to be an actual answer. You could write an answer and accept it. Alternatively, the question itself is fairly poor and probably should just be closed: the question does not include enough information for anyone else to have actually answered it, and the problem sounds like it would fall under the "off-topic, typographical error" close reason anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of `image` are 0, which will cause the `ArgumentException`.

Try setting the values of the values of the pixelWidth and pixelHeight properties to positive integers and see if the exception goes away.

```
image.Source = new WriteableBitmap(
                300,
                300,
                300,
                300,
                PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                null
            );
```